# use jpg as background image

Tags: desktop-background

I am trying to install a custom background image on my xfce desktop. When I browse for the image the file is grayed out regardless of what I do. I trier to chmod it to my username, place it in /usr/share/background/ - nothing helped.

How can I use my image?

thanks,

Answer (score 1):

In the XFCE settings, when you select to change the folder, you cannot select any images. Select the folder where your image is, press Open and THEN select it from the menu.

Comment: I think this is an annoying bug, not intuitive. One would expect that clicking on a folder icon would OPEN it, and it does. But here you have to use the "Open" button to see the non-grayed out choices.